# Objective function goodness if variable holds value above a given constant value

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

In a linear programming formulation, stating that a punishment is to be introduced in an objective minimize function if a variable $S$ holds a value above a given constant $K$ (in the below example, $K = 35$), is quite easy:

- Variable $M$ is included in the objective function to be minimized
- $M \geq 0$
- $S-M-35 \leq 0$

Exemplified explanation: If $S$ gets value $30$, then $M$ may be kept at $0$, so no punishment in objective function. However, if $S$ gets value $40$ in problem solution, $M$ is forced to at least $5$, and consequently a punishment of $5$ is included, just as desired.

But what if we want to include goodness in objective function if $S$ gets value above $35$? E.g., in the previous example, a value of $S$ equal to $30$ should (still) not influence the objective function. But a value of $S$ equal to $40$ should decrease the objective function cost with $5$.

I originally thought this "swap" from badness to goodness would be easy, but I worked on it for almost a full day without finding a solution.

Comment: X-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2911/8

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you want to maximize $\max(S-35,0)$.  You cannot maximize a max or minimize a min in linear programming because these problems are nonconvex.  You would need to introduce binary variables.

In the badness example, you are instead minimizing $\max(S-35,0)$.  Both minimizing a max and maximizing a min are doable with linear programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  :-) 

I already had started to get the feeling that I need an auxiliary binary variable.


FYI: In my case, I think I will end up with a problem redefinition and simply include a scaled down version of S (0.001 * S) directly in the objective function.  Should be fair enough in my case.